# Генерировать рандомные числа в заданном диапазоне с заданным количеством

Tags: php, php7

Мне нужно изменить текст на последовательность из нуля и единиц случайным образом. И что бы количество нулей и единиц равнялось количеству символов которые были изначально в файле.

Я знаю что есть функция

```html
mt_rand(min,max)
```

Но к сожалению она выводит только одно число, а мне надо такое же количество как и символов в файле.

```html
$quantity_string = mb_strlen(strip_tags( implode('', file ('file.txt')) ));
```

Так я узнаю количество символов в тексте, но вот как их заменить на последовательность из 0 и 1 которое будет совпадать с количеством изначальных символов я не знаю.

```html
$change_file1 = '1010101010101010';
file_put_contents('changeValue.txt', $change_file1);
```

А вот так я меняю значение в файле

У кого какие идеи?

UPD:
Я немного изменил код @cassius , но теперь весь текст который был в файле преобразуется только в один символ 0 или 1 (рандомно)

```html
$strSource = file('file/change value.txt'); // исходная строка
$strSouce_to_array = implode($strSource); // строка в массив

            $arraySource = str_split($strSouce_to_array);
            $arrayBinary = array_map(function() {
                return rand(0, 1);
            }, $arraySource);

            $strBinary = implode($arrayBinary); // закодированная строка
            echo $strBinary;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм такой: нужно исходную строку преобразовать в массив, потом каждый элемент массива заменить символом 0 или 1, далее полученный массив преобразовать в строку.

```
$strSource = "Hello world!"; // исходная строка

$arraySource = str_split($strSource);
$arrayBinary = array_map(function() {
    return rand(0, 1);
}, $arraySource);

$strBinary = implode($arrayBinary); // закодированная строка
```

Comment: Стоит обратить внимание, что не всегда будет давать такой результат как ожидается из-за того как php работает с кодировками. [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8f8e2b85547d04dbac8654592cbb41f1036398b)

Comment: А можно ли это сделать не с проверкой строки, а например с проверкой файла?

Comment: Мне нужно данные из файла преобразовать в ноль и один случайным образом

Comment: Я добавил в описание код который я изменил, в чем теперь проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять длину строки и создать случайную такой же длины.

```
$strSource = "Hello World!";
var_dump($strSource, strToRndBin($strSource));
//string(12) "Hello World!"
//string(12) "100010101100"

$strSource = "Привет мир!";
var_dump($strSource, strToRndBin($strSource));
//string(20) "Привет мир!"
//string(11) "10011000110"

function strToRndBin($string) {
    $len = mb_strlen($string);
    $string = '';   
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
        $string .= rand(0,1);   
    return $string;
}
```

Если нужно именно *изменить* строку то, можно передать ссылку

```
$strSource = "Привет мир!";
strToRndBin($strSource);
var_dump($strSource);
//string(11) "11011010110"

function strToRndBin(&$string) {
    $len = mb_strlen($string);
    $string = '';
    
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
        $string .= rand(0,1);
    
    return $string;
}
```